Question about the Uniqueness of representation theorem for open sets on $\mathbb{R}$
This is from the book $<<$Fundamentals of Real Analysis$>>$ by Sterling K Berberian, Section 5.7 F.Riesz's "Rising Sun Lemma".
The author first proves a lemma (The author calls it Riesz's Lemma) :

and in Exercise 1:

Question:
Although the author has given me hints on how to solve this question, I have to admit that I dont know how to even start. I saw these two post Uniqueness of Representation for Open Sets on the Real Line and Representation Theorem for Open Sets on The Real Line (Proof-explanation). These two post are related to the question of mine but both of them does not solve my question using the authors hint (at least for now, but maybe i had mistaken). How do I solve this question using the given hint?

I won't give the full proof, but I'll sketch out some of the bits the author has left out.
First, you prove that any endpoint of $J_m$ is not in $U$. So, for example, if we look at the left endpoint $a_m$ of $J_m = (a_m, b_m)$, if $a_m \in U$ then there must be $n$ such that $a_m \in J_n$. But if that's the case, then we can draw an open interval around $a_m$ that lies entirely within $J_n$ but which also intersects $J_m$ which contradicts the requirement that they are disjoint.
Then, assume that $J_m \cap I_n \neq \emptyset$. Take a point $x \in J_m$, and show that it must also belong to $I_n$ (use the fact that every point in $U$ must belong to some $I_n$). That proves that $J_m \subset \cap I_n$.
Finally, assume that $J_m \subsetneq I_n$. Then show that at least one of the endpoints of $J_m$ is an element of $I_n$. But if it's in $I_n$, then it's in $U$, which we proved can't happen, so the set inclusion must actually be an equality.
